# In C++ why isn't "assert" a keyword?

Tags: c++, assert, keyword

Now "static_assert" is a keyword in C++0x I thought it would be logical to replace the C "assert" macro with an "assert" keyword too.

Answer (score 3):

static_assert is interpreted at compile time so it has to be a keyword so the compiler can  process it.

assert doesn't need to be a keyword, and it doesn't make much sense to make it one, since there are many ways a program might want to respond to assertion success or failure.  Therefore, it makes more sense to implement it in a library, and it is typically implemented as a macro.

Comment: There being multiple ways to respond to a failed assertion is not much of an argument, since even without being a keyword the language specifies behavior

Comment: @Dennis: It specifies behaviour if you use the `assert` defined in `<cassert>`; that doesn't stop you from providing your own definition.

Comment: @Oli: if you include any standard library header, you can not provide your own implementation of `assert`. So for most practical purposes, the language specifies the behavior same as if it were a proper keyword.

Comment: You can redefine the assert (or any other) macro.  You can't redefine a keyword.

Comment: Only if you do not include any standard library headers in that particular translation unit.  Once you do so, all names found in all standard library headers are off limits.  "A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in any standard library header."

Answer (score 2):

`assert` has no compile time meaning, except during Pre-processing. The preprocessor has no knowledge of the C++ language, so a keyword makes no sense.

By contrast, `static_assert` is evaluated at compile time. Making it a keyword makes more sense in that regard. The compiler cares about it's existence.

There are also historic reasons; it was not a keyword in C, and making it one in C++ would have rendered existing assert macros result in undefined behavior.

Comment: C compatibility is not paramount. C++ could choose to add `assert` as a keyword and say that any definitions other than that provided by `<cassert>` (which could be made a deprecated no-op) are UB and must be removed. However, because this doesn't need to happen, and C++ can avoid annoying users by not doing it, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, because it doesn't need it. Existing assertion mechanisms for run-time assertions are perfectly good and don't require language support.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give some possible answers to your question, but a recent proposal indicates that assert may indeed become a keyword in C++17: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4154.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. I agree with the author that assert should be an operator. I especially like the ability to provide a custom diagnostic message similar to static_assert.

Answer (score 1):

`assert` can be implemented in a library, `static_assert` cannot. So `static_assert` gets a keyword because it needs language support, and `assert` doesn't.

Comment: static assert can and has been implemented in a library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html

Comment: @Ferrucio: That's not the same as having it in the language. You could make the same case about lambdas, but the quality is definitely not as high.

Comment: @Ferruccio : The error messages from library-based static_assert implementations tend to be the sort of thing that gives C++ a bad name. Language-based `static_assert` allows for very clean, understandable errors.

Comment: @DeadMG & ildjam: I agree on both points, but that doesn't mean that it can't be implemented in a library.

Comment: @Ferruccio : Essentially a static_assert is just a compiler error, so yes, causing a compiler error in a library is possible. :-P

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done for compatibility with the code already written in c which has assert as a variable name. And hence as oli mentioned we won't be able to compile as assert is no longer macro

Comment: C doesn't have `assert` as a variable name. It's a macro in C as well.

Comment: In addition, C++ does not make any claim to be completely backwards-compatible with C. That's a nice-to-have, not an essential goal. There are plenty of cases where code is not compatible already.

Answer (score 1):

In C++0x (from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.cbclx01/sadec.htm)):

> In C++0x, static assertions can be declared to detect and diagnose common usage errors at compile time.

this is `static_assert` syntax:

```
>>-static_assert--(--constant-expression--,--string-literal----->
```

where `constant-expression` must be contextually converted to `bool`. If it converts to `false`, then the compiler will emit an error according the `string-literal`.

So, this is basically an extension of the language that needs a keyword. It is not a runtime mechanism.

Again from the document linked above:

> The addition of static assertions to the C++ language has the following benefits:
>
> 1. Libraries can detect common usage errors at compile time.
> 2. Implementations of the C++ Standard Library can detect and diagnose common usage errors, improving usability.
> 3. You can use a static_assert declaration to check important program invariants at compile time.